# CKEDITOR5 v. 29.0.0 Insert Image

Tags: ckeditor5

In one project with version 28.0.0 i have used this code to insert image in the content

```
const imageElement = writer.createElement('image', {
                src: imageUrl
            });
editor.model.insertContent(imageElement, editor.model.document.selection);
```

now with version 29.0.0 this does not work. No error in the console. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With Ck5 29.0.0 for to do this i have resolved with:

```
const imageElement = writer.createElement('imageBlock', {
            src: imageUrl
        });
editor.model.insertContent(imageElement, editor.model.document.selection);
```